# Обороты на определенный период SQL

Tags: sql-server

Нужно вывести обороты на определенный период, а именно, с октября по март. 
есть **datetime1**, **datetime2** (с датами) и **value**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, вообще-то нужно задавать вопрос более конкретно. Вот вам пара примеров.
Вариант номер один - выберем все значения в определенном интервале:

```
select * from Periods p
where p.BeginDate > '20.01.2014' and p.EndDate < '20.02.2016'
```

В данном примере `BeginDate` и `EndDate` это Ваши `datetime1` и `datetime2`. Ну это просто к примеру. `Periods` - это произвольная таблица из которой делаем выборку.

Перейдем ко второму примеру, это если Вам нужна сумма по определенному столбцу или обороты, как Вы говорите:

```
select SUM(p.Value) from PeriodDictionaries p
where p.BeginDate > '20.01.2014' and p.EndDate < '20.02.2016'
```

Так как конкретного вопроса я не услышал, то более конкретный ответ дать не могу. Обороты за определенный период могут рассчитываться по разному, есть такие названия как приход, расход, сальдо и т.п., поэтому и результаты могут быть разными. Как суммы, так и сводные таблицы, так и разности.

Comment: Да, спасибо, есть в другой таблице documentCost, мне нужно вывести эту стоимость за определенный период. как ее за JOINить к первой таблице с датами?

Comment: Чтобы связать две таблицы нужна какая-то связь, к примеру по идентификатору. Добавьте больше деталей. То есть что есть в первой таблице и что есть во второй таблице. `Правильно заданный вопрос - это уже часть ответа.`

Comment: у меня получилось, я добавил в свой запрос другую таблицу с documentCost и Клиентом, само задание такого. Нужно вывести distinct клиентов с ихним суммарным оборотом за определенный период, у меня не получается засуммировать их. закрепил текущий код

Comment: @Niflungar, ох...не читабельно...сейчас постараюсь разобрать

Comment: извините, зеленый пока в это деле..

Comment: @Niflungar, используйте `Group By` для выборки уникальных клиентов с суммами. Почитайте в интернете как использовать, думаю разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что уделили мне свое время. Дальше буду сам разбираться.

Comment: @Niflungar, не за что. Удачи Вам в решении Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Может пригодится, считаем кол-во записей по месяцам,используя Pivot.

```
SELECT YourProduct, [01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12]
From   (
       SELECT YourProduct,id,month (transactionStartDate) AS DataS
       FROM   YourDataBase..yourTable
        )Test
PIVOT  (Count (id) FOR DataS IN ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12]) ) Отчёт
```